# Build failure after Xcode 7.3 update

Tags: objective-c, xcode7.3

notice:no Pods.framework question.

build error:

> ld: in
>   '/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation',
>   missing required architecture armv7 in file
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
>   (2 slices) for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Are you building for a device or for `Generic iOS Device`?

Comment: Yes, building for a device

Comment: I've seen a similar problem building for Generic.  7.3 is full of bugs.

Comment: Have Fixed it . 1. Remove system frameworks in the path $(PROJECT_DIR).   2.add the system frameworks again.